# Use URL to set model as true or false

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have a todo APP and I would like to have a link where the user can click and set the "todo" as complete without deleting it from my database.

I use CBV but cannot figure out how do it :

I tried

**views.py :**

```
class TodoDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
model = Todo
success_url = '/'
template_name = 'dashboard/dashboard_confirm_delete.html'

def completeTodo(request, todo_id):
    todo = Todo.objects.get(pk=todo_id)
    todo.complete = True
    todo.save()
```

But it delete it from my DB and it does not set it to true.

**My models.py**

```
class Todo(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Nom de l'utilisateur")
text = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Nom de la Todo")
complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: `But it delete it ..` whilst some other code can be deleting these records, this code does not.

Comment: You defined this as a `DeleteView`, so the `completeTodo` function is not relevant here.

Comment: @IvanStarostin: in fact it does, since it is a `DeleteView`, so the function is irrelevant.

Comment: Did not notice that.

Comment: So function view is best for that ? Because I know how to do it with Function Based View, I just wanted to know if it was easier with CBV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define a `DeleteView`, and deleting the object, is just part of the `delete` control flow. In order to change the behavior, we can override the `delete` function, like:

```
class TodoDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Todo
    pk_url_kwarg = 'todo_id'
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'dashboard/dashboard_confirm_delete.html'

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        success_url = self.get_success_url()
        self.object.complete = True
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```

The `pk_url_kwarg` is necessary to use this to obtain the primary key to filter and retrieve the correct object with `get_object()`.

The reason why we might want to use a `DeleteView`, is because people can make a `DELETE` request on that endpoint.